# NestJS циркулярная зависимость (наверное)

Tags: backend, nestjs

Код выдает такую ошибку:

```
[Nest] 11732  - 17.06.2023, 18:30:35   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ComplaintsService (ComplaintRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the
in the ComplaintsModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is ComplaintsModule a valid NestJS module?
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current ComplaintsModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ComplaintsModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ComplaintsService (ComplaintRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the ComplaintsModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is ComplaintsModule a valid NestJS module?
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current ComplaintsModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ComplaintsModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })
```

Bing ai подсказывает что проблема в циркулярной зависимости, но я во всех трех модулях указал forwarRef. Так в чем же проблема? Подскажите пожалуйста

[image: Код]

Comment: Скажите, для чего модулю постов зависеть от модуля пользователей, и для чего модулю пользователей зависеть от модуля постов? (Вопрос наполовину риторический, я вижу ваш код).

Очень часто новички в Nest.js любят импортировать друг в друга модули для "переиспользуемости", что приводит к десяткам `forwardRef` и подобным ошибкам. Для начала, если вам вообще пришлось использовать `forwardRef`, то это значит, что вы спроектировали систему неправильно.

Comment: Если вам в модуле А нужен модуль Б, а в модуле Б нужен модуль А, то, вероятно, будет правильным решением объединить их в один модуль. 

Конкретно в вашем случае, как я понимаю, у вас просто в обоих сервисах реализованы CRUD методы, и вы хотите их переиспользовать. Можно например написать какой-нибудь репозиторий, который не будет являться частью никакого модуля, и потом просто импортить его в нужные вам модули, вместе с `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()`, `MongooseModule.forFeature()` etc.